# Combining two column correspondingly

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, outlook

I have imported Outlook email CSV data and dropped unnecessary columns.

```
    CC(Name)                           CC(Email)
  A; B; C; D; E         abc@aa; def@dd; asd@aa; wer@dd; qwer@qq
  B; F; E; R; W         def@dd; wer@aa; qwer@qq; wer@ee; wee@rr
```

And now I have these two columns which I initially wanted to extract together
 like `"A<abc@aa>; B<def@aa>----"` as one column.

As preprocessing, I want to put <> onto emails and make it one correspondingly.
Is it technically possible by using Pandas actually..?

In my case of example,

CC(Name) column consists of objects such as

```
Mr.Chicken;Water;Ms.Cat;Forest;Dog
```

And correspondingly, CC(Email) column has exactly like

```
/0-org-name/ou=administrative group/cn=recipient/cn=unique num;aaa@we;/o-same-org------
```

Outlook export method gave me this kinda weird address because they use org account or something..

Does the "/" matter when trying to separate the str?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using list comprehension with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip), [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
df['output'] = ['; '.join([f'{n1}<{e1}>' for n1, e1 in zip(n.split('; '), e.split('; '))])
                for n, e in zip(df['CC(Name)'], df['CC(Email)'])]
print(df)
```

[out]

```
        CC(Name)                                CC(Email)                                                  output
0  A; B; C; D; E  abc@aa; def@dd; asd@aa; wer@dd; qwer@qq  A<abc@aa>; B<def@dd>; C<asd@aa>; D<wer@dd>; E<qwer@qq>
1  B; F; E; R; W  def@dd; wer@aa; qwer@qq; wer@ee; wee@rr  B<def@dd>; F<wer@aa>; E<qwer@qq>; R<wer@ee>; W<wee@rr>
```

---

#### Update

In case of `float` types, you can try using `str()`:

```
df['output'] = ['; '.join([f'{n1}<{e1}>' for n1, e1 
                           in zip(str(n).split('; '), str(e).split('; '))])
                for n, e in zip(df['CC(Name)'], df['CC(Email)'])]
```

Comment: Nice solution :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment!  That [out] is exactly like what I wanted!
I tried your code into my df but it stated "'float' object has no attribute 'split'".

I know what this means but I have never used "n,e" split method so I have no idea how to fix it...

Comment: Can you identify the problem row? Which rows is type `float`?

Comment: Float one did not output errors and could see the result.
It was like 
"name;name;name;<adress><adress><adress>" 
so it seemed like the loop only effects one time only for me..

Comment: I checked column didn't have " ; " out of separators.
Does the fact that dtype of CC(name)and(email) was Object actually matter?

Comment: Can you post that line as an example to the question above?

Comment: Yes, sir.  I checked other rows whether they have different weird stuff in it but so far it follows the same form..

Comment: I think I spotted the problem. Actually my actual columns didn't have space after " ; ". 

As I played with the sample df, it seems like if both columns don't contain space after " ; ", it worked like "name;name;name;<email>;<email>;<email>"  but after I put space after every single " ; ", it worked as I wanted...

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy! Assuming your data is in a dataframe `df`:

```
df['cc_full'] = df['CC(Name)'] + "<" + df['CC(Email)'] + ">"
```

That should give you the column you need.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it gave me rows like

name; name; name; <adress; adress; adress>

Rows I wanted are like 

name<adress>; name<adress>; name<adress>...

Comment: Ah so it gave you a single row with all the data in it? In that case see the answer by Chris A - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60390921/7184996